# How to compare a value with a list of values

Tags: json, rest, groovy, soapui

I am trying to perform an assertion where every instance of a region id matches the region id that's put through in the request. As an example, if in the request put in the number '736', then for each instance of region id within the response they should all be '736'. However when i perform at the asset, it states it's false and i beleive it is because the output is within a list so the == does not work. How can i get the request and each item in the list form the response to match?

Below is the code:

```
def hotelregionid = json.regions.hotels.regionId
assert hotelregionid != null
def hotelregionid_request = messageExchange.modelItem.testStep.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue("regionid")
assert hotelregionid.every {it == hotelregionid_request} -- this is where the assertion fails.

log.info hotelregionid
log.info hotelregionid_request
```

The error message it outputs is:

```
assert hotelregionid.every {it == hotelregionid_request} | | | false [[xxx,xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,xxx,xxx,xxx,xxx,xxx]]
```

The log.info provided when i comment out the assert is the same number which I will value as xxx.:

[[xxx, xxx, xxx, xxx, xxx,xxx,xxx]] - this is for `hotelregionid`

xxx - this is for `hotelregionid_request`

RAW RESPONSE:

```
{
    "xxx": [{
        "regionId": xxx,
        "xxx": [{
                "xxx": [{

                    "regionId": xxx

                }],

                "xxx": xxx
            },

            {
                "xxx": [{
                    "regionId": xxx
                }],
                "xxx": xxx
            }
        ]

    }]
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you please show the raw response?

Comment: Just grabbing the raw response now...

Comment: Is the above ok Rao?

Comment: Was that a complete structure or you cut down some info? If you cut down, the solution may not work. So please provide right response.

Comment: It's a cut down version because the response is huge, am I ok to send the full response to you?

Comment: Sure you can send it thru github/gist/pastbin. I am sure other solution might also have not worked if the response is same.

Comment: Yeah solution below did not work. i did try flatten somewhere else before posting this question.

Comment: Ok this is the whole raw response from soap which is strange as it does not finish off the response, so bits of the ending is missing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136701/discussion-between-rao-and-bruceybandit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the `script assertion`.

Note that define the expected value in the below variable.

EDIT: updated answer based on OP's full response [here](http://pastebin.com/raw/vBD42kss)

```
//Change the value as needed
def expectedRegionId = 736
assert context.response, 'Response is null or empty'

def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(context.response)

def sb = new StringBuffer()
json.regions.each { region ->
    assert region.regionId == expectedRegionId
    region.hotels.each { hotel ->
        assert hotel.regionId == expectedRegionId
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your output, `hotelregionid` is a List of Lists

So you can use `flatten` to get it back to just a List of integers:

```
assert hotelregionid.flatten().every {it == hotelregionid_request}
```

Comment: I recieve this error when I included your method tim: No signature of method: java.lang.String.flatten() is applicable for argument types: () values: [] Possible solutions: take(int), wait(), intern(), println()